# Android Touch Pad

Tags: java, c#, android, cursor, motionevent

I'm looking for developing a remote control app to my PC, One of my tools on my project is moving cursor with touch gesture

I use Motion Event  for tracking pointers, I have tried many times but there's no sensitivity.

This is my first try

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastX = event.getX();
            lastY = event.getY();
            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        default:

            float xx = event.getX() - lastX;
            float yy = event.getY() - lastY;

            x = xx*speed;
            y =yy*speed;

            lastX = event.getX();
            lastY = event.getY();

            break;
```

> Speed is a constant

Then i send **x** , **y**  to a C# program to move cursor, but it didn't work very good, It was really slow for a big move, So i tried to increase speed but it became very bad for a small move such as clicking on Exit icon.

So i tried not to make speed a constant i make it depends on some thing change when x&y change, Some thing like distance.

This is my second try

```
  double distance = Math.sqrt((xx * xx) + (yy * yy));   
  speed =(float)(distance*c);
```

> **C** is a constant to make distance greater or lower

But it wasn't very good, it didn't have any sensitivity, I can't make a circle with it and some times it goes far away from what i want

And this is my C# Code

```
 private void linearSmoothMove(Point newPosition, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        Point start = Cursor.Position;

        // Find the vector between start and newPosition
        double deltaX = newPosition.X - start.X;
        double deltaY = newPosition.Y - start.Y;
        if (moving == null || !moving.IsAlive)
        {
            moving = new Thread(() =>
            {


                // start a timer
                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();

                double timeFraction = 0.0;

                do
                {
                    timeFraction = (double)stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks / duration.Ticks;
                    if (timeFraction > 1.0)
                        timeFraction = 1.0;

                    int intX = start.X + ((int)Math.Round(timeFraction * deltaX));
                    int intY = start.Y + ((int)Math.Round(timeFraction * deltaY));
                    Console.WriteLine(intX + "," + intY);
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(intX, intY);

                    Thread.Sleep(5);
                } while (timeFraction < 1.0);
            });
            moving.Start();
        }
    }
```

> newPosition is x&y come from android.

Any suggestion for better performance ?